# HTML table on Outlook desktop app not formatted as other e-mail services

Tags: html, outlook

I'm trying to send an e-mail with a simple HTML table but in the Outlook desktop app it gets really awful and in any other e-mail services it gets correctly but add some spaces between the first paragraph and the table. I've tried to do a lot things that I saw on internet and I can't solve though. Here are some photos to show what's happening. My intention is to let the table similar to the web version but without this spaces between the paragraph and the table.

[Outlook desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfODz.png)

[Outlook web and other e-mail services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeEoD.png)

Here's my HTML code

```
<p>AUTO - INFORMAÇÃO SOBRE A SC</p>
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" style="border-color: black; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;">
<tr>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;">Data Hora Evento</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;">Solicitação</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;">Ator</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;">Usuário</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;">Tipo</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; font-weight: bold; vertical-align:top;">Situação</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align:top;">05/06/2020 14:42:13</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align:top;">42475</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align:top;">Aprovador</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align:top;">solici</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align:top;">Incluir</td>
<td height="40" width="167" align="center" style="text-align: center; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align:top;">Solicitada</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>INFORMAÇÕES.</p>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Outlook desktop app uses a horribly outdated HTML parser. You are right to use the old-style height, width and align properties, as Outlook does not typically recognize styles. However, if you are not getting the results you want, you may have to devise a simpler, fallback layout for Outlook.